# Grafana Latency Query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, latency

I have a simple API application running and I'm using a custom Post manager to 'PUT' here periodically. My concern is that some of the 'PUTS' are taking over 50ms to complete .
In Grafana I setup the following prom QL query to try and find these requests

(sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{exception="None", app="Myapp", method="PUT"}[5m])) by (le) > 0.05)

It seems from the results i get back this is pulling in all buckets showing me all of them for the value of 0.05556? [grafana-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH2aq.png) but not actually showing me all requests that are over 50ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` metrics count the number of requests since last service restart with durations smaller or equal to the `le` label value. For example, `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{le="0.1"}` counts the number of requests with durations smaller or equal to 0.1 seconds (e.g. 100ms).

The number of buckets and their boundaries are set by the application, which exposes the histogram. Buckets' count and buckets' boundaries affect the precision of the histogram. For example, if the `http_server_requests_seconds`  histogram exposes only the following `le` boundaries: `0.01`, `0.1`, `1` and `Inf`, then it is impossible to calculate with 100% precision the number of requests with the duration exceeding 50ms. But it is possible to calculate the exact number of requests with durations bigger than 10ms, 100ms or 1s.

Note that `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` metrics expose per-bucket counters, which start counting requests **since the service restart**. If you need to obtain per-bucket request distribution over some time window, then you need to wrap the `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` into [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function with the specified time window in square brackets. For example, the following query returns per-bucket request distribution over the last hour:

```
increase(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket[1h])
```

P.s. see also https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350 .

Comment: Thanks this is very useful. This part where you mention - "But it is possible to calculate the exact number of requests with durations bigger than 10ms, 100ms or 1s."  Thats why im trying to find out. But when I include the following [5m])) by (le) > 0.05) (request greater then 50ms)  as per my screenshot it doesn't show me full count in whole numbers like there were 100 requests over 50ms etc . Thats what im trying to achieve

Comment: The `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` counts the number of requests. It doesn't contain measurement values. So it has no sense comparing it to 0.05 or to any other measurement value. The measurement bounds are stored in `le` label of the `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` metric as described in the answer.